# How to find out Processor GPIO maximum source current and maximum sink current of that pin

Tags: current-source

How to find out Processor one GPIO pin maximum source current and maximum sink current? In datasheet mentioned IoL and IoH, is it same for GPIO source and sink current also?

Comment: Can you give us the datasheet?

Comment: Its a IMX6 solo Free scale processor

Comment: http://cache.freescale.com/files/32bit/doc/data_sheet/IMX6SDLAEC.pdf

Comment: I can't find it either, looking at the datasheet on page 39.  Looks like a hard current limit is not specified, but the Vih/Vil was tested using 1mA when register ipp_dse >= 3, so 1mA is a safe value.  If you need 2-3mA it's probably ok as long as you aren't running hot.

Comment: yes you are correct , i also try to find in datasheet but its not clearly mentioned. I am going to send mail to Free scale. thank you very much for your time to help me.

Comment: See also [What is drive strength a measurement of?](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/164446/29811)

Comment: Is it too late to send it back and swap it for something else?

Answer (score 3):

That is one of the most useless datasheets I have ever seen.

The maximum current levels for GPIO pins are not specified in the data sheet.  This apparently is intentional on Freescale's part.

This question was brought up in a [Freescale forum](https://community.freescale.com/thread/322294).  A Freescale employee,  Yuri Muhin answered.  In the last paragraph, he says "Maximum current levels ... are not specified."

Here is the full text of his answer:

> Re: Source and Sink Current on i.MX6 SoloLite Yuri Muhin Employee Yuri
>   Muhin Apr 14, 2014 1:02 AM (in response to David Boling)
>
> There are values of load current in the Datasheet(s), which relate
>   to some typical configurations, in particular - in order to guarantee
>   specified output voltages. For more accurate (application depended)
>   estimations IBIS models should be  applied.
>
> Really the data of i.MX Datasheets specify maximum / minimum
>   voltage levels in relation with current loads. These current values
>   should not be considered as maximum allowed ones, just as reasonable.
>   IBIS model provides current-voltage  curves for pins in order to
>   calculate real currents and voltages on pins.
>
> Another case, that corresponding voltage (high, low) levels may not
>   be in ranges, shown in Datasheet and defined as logical 0 or 1.
>
> Maximum current values (which do not decrease life time and do not
>   damage the device) are not specified, because they are application
>   dependent and relate to general thermal estimations. Say, if a
>   separate pin can sink high current, say greater than 8 mA, this does
>   not mean that all pins may be loaded (simultaneously) with such
>   values. Strictly speaking the i.MX6  is not intended to be used as
>   high current GPIO source or sink, assuming that special buffers or I/O
>   expanders should be applied for it.
>
> Have a great day, Yuri

Have a great day, indeed.

Comment: I think most uC/CPUs with pretenses at high perf lack that info. Try finding it for the RPi; see https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=44&t=12498

Comment: Looking at that Freescale datasheet, the max power supply for the GPIOs (combined) is limited (not quite unlike RPi), but they really sucked at explaining that.

Comment: And also try to figure it out on (the usually well documented) TI high-perf Sitara chips https://e2e.ti.com/support/arm/sitara_arm/f/791/p/320778/1116251