# How do I calculate maximum current that each pin of PC8575 is able to sink?

Tags: current, integrated-circuit, datasheet, nxp

http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/PCF8575.pdf

Can somebody tell me which parameter one should look for while looking for calculating maximium Current source/sinked by a pin.

Answer (score 2):

The output current is listed as I<sub>OL</sub> and I<sub>OH</sub>:

[image: PC8575 output current]

Please note that these are the values that guarantee not to exceed the specified voltage drop (V<sub>OL</sub>, V<sub>OH</sub>). If you need a smaller voltage drop, you need to use a smaller current. (See also [What is drive strength a measurement of?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/164446/29811))